# Conditional Probability of Poisson Process

Tags: conditional-probability

I have seen many questions on here regarding the conditional probability of the Poisson Process however I have not seen an option for the opposite

i.e \begin{align}
P(N_T = n | N_t = m)
\end{align}

where $T > t > 0$ and $n > m > 0.$

Could someone help me understand this please?
Am I missing something obvious?

Sorry for the poor format this is my first post.

Comment: What do you mean by "an option"?

Comment: Sorry I meant an answer

Comment: An answer to which question? Are you looking for an expression that is equal to $P(N_T=n\mid N_t=m)$?

Comment: Yes sorry. I have only seen expressions equivalent to the formula given above where t>T>0 and m>n>0. For example I would like to know P(N_2 = 5 | N_1 = 2)

Answer (score 0):

Due to the memorylessness of the Poisson process,

$$
P(N_T=n\mid N_t=m)=P(N_{T-t}=n-m\mid N_0=0)=\mathrm e^{-\lambda(T-t)}\frac{(\lambda(T-t))^{n-m}}{(n-m)!}\;,
$$

where $\lambda$ is the rate parameter of the Poisson process.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I had a feeling it may have been the case but wasn't sure and needed confirmation so thank you for clarifying.